# If $f$ is continuous and $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$, prove $f=0$ without FTC. Small issue with solution.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-explanation

> If $f$ is continuous and $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$, prove $f=0$
>   without FTC.

Question is from Courant Intro to Calculus any Analysis I, s2.3-3.  It comes before fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC).  This is solution:

[image]

How do we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n$?

Answer (score 2):

We do indeed have $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$ only for $x \in (-1,1)$. This implies that $f(x) = 0 \forall x \in (-1,1)$. But since $f$ is *continuous* this implies $f(x) = 0$ also for $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

Comment: Ah thats what it meant silly me.

Comment: @helios321 But I agree it was a little bit difficult to understand in the order they presented the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can have this alternative solution without applying FTC. Consider $\psi(x)=\int_{0} ^{x} f(t)dt$, then $\psi$ is differentiable at each $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Therefore $f$ is  also differentiable and $f'(x)=f(x)$ also $f(0)=0$. Now consider $\phi(x)=f(x) \exp(-x)$, then $\phi ' =0 ,$ therefore $\phi(x) = c,$ a constant, but $\phi(0)=0$. This implies $f(x)=0. \psi $ is differentiable at $x_0$ because $|\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(y)}{x-y}-f(x_0)|=|\frac{1}{x-y}\int_x ^y[f(u)-f(x_0)]du |< \epsilon$ for any $x_0-\delta<x \leq x_0 \leq y < x_0+\delta .$

Comment: How do you infer that $\psi$ is differentiable *without* using FTC?

Comment: You don't need FTC because $f$ is continuous so if you compute the difference of the differential quotient and $f(x)$ , it will be smaller than $\epsilon$ by the continuity of $f$.